# Running sum until a negative number

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sum, empty-list

Please how can I use the index 0 in a for-loop when testing an empty array for a drumming sum.
Also, the single negative value returns zero
The sum should stop when a negative number is encountered

```
  let sum = 0;

  let lenArr = arr.length;

  for (let i = 0; i <= lenArr - 1; i++) {
    if (lenArr === 0) {
      break;
    }

    if (arr[i] > 0) {
      sum = sum + arr[i];
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

  return sum;
}

let input = [];

runningSum(input);
```

Comment: what is the problem? is the code not working? it does work though not the bet design. What should be the result of input `[-1]` if not 0? your loop will also stop when it encounters a 0, since 0 is not greater than 0

Comment: Your code works. It could do with a little pruning, but essentially it does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

For an empty array the for loop would not be executed and it will return 0.
You can remove the if condition to check length of array inside for loop.